# APR vs. Investment performance: is it that simple?

Tags: home-loan, france

I have a home loan, with an APR of 1.71%, and a savings account, with a state-regulated performance of 2.5% tax-free.

Is choosing where to put my money (ie. pay back the loan, or put the money in savings) as simple as 1.71 < 2.5 => Save it (and in general, save the money if you can get better than 1.71%), or is the math more complicated? If so, could you explain that math to me?

For the purpose of this question, let's assume that quality of life, usefulness of the savings, opportunity costs and so on do not matter.

Comment: Is the 2.5% unlimited? Meaning can you earn 2.5% on an unlimited amount?

Comment: Also what country is this? Are you able to claim a mortgage interest tax deduction?

Comment: @DStanley There is a cap at 61.200€, my wife and I each have one, so 122.400€, which is not bad. The interest rate is fixed when the account is opened. (2.5 is 2014 - 1986 rate was 4.6% bad at the time, pretty good now)

Comment: @DStanley Added a France tag (no interest tax deduction), but let's keep it general. Basically, I owe money at x%, and can save at y%. It is as simple as comparing x and y or is there some complicated calculation with the length of the loan, and so on...

Comment: Is this a fixed rate or floating rate loan?

Comment: And the tax deduction is important because the _after-tax_ rate might be less than the investment rate, changing the answer.

Comment: It's not *mathematically* more complicated, but it might give you *psychological* peace of mind to not have the debt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the savings account pays 2.5% on any balance amount (i.e. no minimums or maximums), then yes it would be better to put money in the savings account vs the mortgage. You could either let it grow and pay off the mortgage once the account balance equals the principal owed, or periodically withdraw some funds to make extra payments (reducing the amount of mortgage interest paid).

Other things that may change the equation, though:

- Availability of a tax deduction for mortgage interest (reduces the effective after-tax mortgage rate)
- If you are paying PMI or other mortgage insurance because you owe more than 80% of the loan value
- Floating-rate mortgage (savings might be better *now* but could change over time)
- Prepayment penalties
- Cap on savings account balance (just limits how much you can exploit the difference)
- Other debts (typically the highest interest rate debt should be considered first)

Comment: you were conned -  the "2% !" interest is just one of those absurd bonuses on the first few dollars.

Answer (score 2):

Generally - yes. Take a loan at lower interest, invest at higher interest. Happens all the time. Make sure you do not run a serious risk of not being able to get out of the deal when interest rates changes and make sure to read the samll print.

Also make some math on relevance. You right now talk of 0.79% per year. That is pathetic, as total amount, unless you can run millions on it. On a 100.000 setting (currency is irrelevant) that is 780 per year, 65 per month (so for 100k EUR that is 65 EUR per month profits). Not sure you want to do all that hassle for that amount of money.

That said, on the other side (foregoing state regulated performance) it is not exactly harder than being able to look around to get 8%+ per year+ for EUR at the moment, if you know where to look (spend some time on google). THAT would change the difference seriously and make this an endeavour that is worth something.